# Changed values do not show after PDF conversion

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I've created a html page, which has some values that can be changed through a textfield. An example of how this works:

```
Voornaam: <h3 class="title1">Test</h3>
      <input type="text" id="myTextField1"/>
      <input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change" onclick="change1()"/><br/>
```

Which is linked to the function:

```
function change1(){
   var myNewTitle = document.getElementById('myTextField1').value;
   if( myNewTitle.length==0 ){
       alert('Write Some real Text please.');
   return;
   }
   var titles = document.getElementsByClassName('title1');
   Array.prototype.forEach.call(titles,title => {
    title.innerHTML = myNewTitle;
   });
}
```

What it's supposed to change here is:

```
<p class="title1">Test.</p><p class="title2">Achternaam</p>
```

It does change this value, however I have created a html to PDF method using wkhtmltopdf. And after converting, the first value is returned. My new value is not in the PDF version.

I can provide an example of the way I convert html to PDF, however I feel like this is unnecessary as it is a simply command using wkhtmltopdf.

Could anyone explain to me how to make it so my new value will be converted and seen in the PDF.

Edit:
Some explanation of how the conversion works.

On the bottom of my html page there is:

```
  <?php
         $link_address = 'convert.php';
          echo "<a href='".$link_address."'>converten naar pdf.</a>";
          ?>
```

Which runs this:

```
$command = '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf [my link here] '.$path;

if($status = 1){
shell_exec($command);
echo 'De offerte is omgezet naar pdf en opgeslagen in: '. $path;
}
```

This does work, but as I said.. not with my changed value.

Comment: I took a look at "wkhtmltopdf" and it's apparently a command line tool. Which means it processes the HTML document on your hard drive, which will of course be unaffected by JS changes to the DOM in a browser. However if you are already taking this into consideration, you _do_ need to get more explicit about how and when you're doing the conversion to PDF.

Comment: It is true, I run a command inside my php to do the conversion. I will edit my post to explain it further.

Comment: Again, you aren't changing anything *on the server*. The JavaScript code runs in the client's browser, and those changes only happen in the RAM of the computer you're using to look at the web page. Otherwise anybody could permanently change random websites at will, without having to hack the server first.

Comment: Is there any way to get this done then? Or is it just impossible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the changes to the server. Exactly like submitting a form works.

One way to do this is to make your JS code also set hidden input fields:

```
<form id="changes" action="convert.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="title">
  <!-- more inputs here -->
  <input type="submit" value="converten naar pdf.">
</form>
```

When a user submits that form, your `convert.php` can now

- read the HTML document
- replace the original title with `$_POST['title']`
- save the altered document as temp file
- run the conversion

Comment: I will have to take a look at this as I'm not very experienced. Is there any chance you could give a simple example of this based on my code? Perhaps a JSFiddle would be very appreciated.

Comment: Here's example code for `<input type="hidden" name="voornaam">`: http://ideone.com/16EzT1

Comment: Thank you very much, I will be trying this out.

Comment: Should I be linking my wktohtml function to the send button?

Comment: Yes, but only in the sense that the send button will send the form values to `convert.php`, which will in turn run the command. To be clear: you still have to use *both* the JS code and the PHP code. At the end of the PHP example, where I'm simply echoing the generated HTML, you'd instead save the file, then call the conversion command like you originally did.